# Is it more performant to add inferred keywords to Groovy

Tags: groovy

Groovy is an interpreted language. Right?
So I'm thinking: isn't it better to be verbose when we can to lessen the burden on the interpreter?

For example, in the following case:

```
def getStringy() {
   def result = ...
   ...

   result
}
```

Groovy will know that we want to `return result` but isn't it more performant to write that explicitly?

Also, isn't it better to specify the type of the methods arguments when we can? Some people here disagree with me. For example:

```
void specialSort(list) {
     // do sorting of a list
}
```

What about semi-colons? What about public keywords? Do these matters affect performance in any way?

Comment: _"Groovy is an interpreted language. Right?"_ Nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy is a compiled language. Before being executed, your code is going to be compiled, to a normal JVM-compatible bytecode classes.

Write the code, so you and others can easily read and understand it. Leave the compilation work for the compiler.

The only exception is, when you explicitly leverage *a possibility to have dynamic code*, e.g. using GroovyShell, to execute custom code, passed to the program as a string. You can do it in runtime. It will still be a 2 step (compile, then execute) process, and compilation results may be easily cached, if you want to call them often.
In that particular case, you'll have more headache about how to make it secure, and safe, then how to speed-up compilation process.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy is compiled to Java Bytecode and then is run on the JVM

So, your first statement is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

> Groovy is an interpreted language. Right?

**NO**

Groovy is a compiled language. Before code is being executed it gets compiled to a normal JVM-compatible bytecode classes just like java code.

> Groovy will know that we want to return result but isn't it more
>   performant to write that explicitly?

As groovy avoids the boilerplate code you don't need to add the `return` statement (I personally prefer to write the `return` for readability purpose).

Groovy understands that whatever is on the last line of the function, you want to return it.

> Declaring the type of variable

Groovy is dynamic language.

When using def in Groovy, the actual type holder is Object (so you can assign any object to variables defined with def, and return any kind of object if a method is declared returning def).

> What about public keywords?

Groovy considers classes and methods public. So you don’t have to use the public modifier everywhere. Only if it’s not public, you should put a visibility modifier.

As stated above groovy has given us way to avoid the boilerplate code, we can use it that way OR java code is also valid in groovy so it's just matter of taste.